# Xt error: Can't open display, if using default DISPLAY

Tags: macos, docker, x11, x11-forwarding, xquartz

### Overview

I'm attempting to get XQuartz to work on OSX so I can do X11 forwarding via Docker. I'm following [the instructions here](https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/docker/images/dockerfile/2015/04/22/docker-gui-osx/). I believe my question may be answered by just the first part, but just in case (to avoid the XY problem), I've provided the second part as well.

### Installation

I've installed it via homebrew, via `brew cask install xquartz`. Then I `open -a XQuartz` to start it.

### Local xterms

Testing it out, if I try to open an `xterm`, it does not work:

```
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3wncZULdXC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

The pseudo-file exists, though:

```
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3wncZULdXC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ ls -alh $DISPLAY
srw-rw-rw-  1 csaftoiu  wheel     0B May  6 21:12 /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3wncZULdXC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

I *can* open an xterm via XQuartz. Then:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

This value works from a regular OSX too:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 xterm
# opens xterm, waits for it to finish
$
```

The following do not work though, not sure why based on [the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/what-does-display-0-0-actually-mean):

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0 xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 127.0.0.1:0
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ DISPLAY=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`:0 xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.15:0
```

Note that `xinit` does work for some reason:

```
$ xinit

xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
# opens xterm, waits for it to finish
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down
```

#### Question 1: What is XQuartz actually listening on?

---

### Docker Forwarding with socat

In any case, moving on, this `socat` command does not work:

```
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
```

Running that, from another window I do:

```
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`:0 ubuntu:14.04 bash
root@912eec31b8cb:/# apt-get update && apt-get install xterm
... such install, wow ...
root@912eec31b8cb:/# xterm
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
root@912eec31b8cb:/# echo $DISPLAY
192.168.1.15:0
```

From the `socat` window I get:

```
2016/06/14 21:08:15 socat[24289] E connect(5, LEN=68 AF=1 "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3wncZULdXC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0", 68): Connection refused
```

I can't use the DISPLAY variable that works, either:

```
MacBook-Pro:opencv-gui csaftoiu$ socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\":0\"
2016/06/14 21:09:43 socat[24309] E connect(5, LEN=4 AF=1 ":0", 4): No such file or directory
```

Now, this is not a UNIX-CLIENT IP. But, I don't know *what* `DISPLAY=:0` is connecting to. It's certainly not port 6000 since that's the port it used to be listening on. If I change it to `6005`, to forward to `6000`, and make the Docker container DISPLAY be `$(ipconfig getifaddr en0):5` instead, then the connection is of course refused:

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:6005,reuseaddr,fork TCP:localhost:6000
2016/06/14 21:20:32 socat[25379] E connect(8, LEN=16 AF=2 127.0.0.1:6000, 16): Connection refused
```

#### Question 2: How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I hadn't restarted after re-installing XQuartz. I restarted, and now it works. :).

Comment: The instructions I was following did say to log out and back in for xQuarts to work, which I did.  Rebooting was the key piece I was missing too, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

## Dockerized UI Apps in Docker for Desktop MacOS 2018+. Updated in in 2021.

Went through all the pain to get the simplest version possible that does not depend on checking port, ip, etc... Here it is.

- Running version `XQuartz 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4)`
- Docker version `docker version 18.06.1-ce`

Make sure to install XQuartz (Updated with `2021 change`)

```
$ brew install socat
$ brew install --cask xquartz
```

- Don't forget to close logout and log back in.

> ATTENTION: At this point, make sure to reboot your host (MacOS for instance). The following error is related to when you don't: `E connect(5, LEN=2 AF=1 "<anon>", 2): Invalid argument`

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
2021/04/04 17:28:58 socat[40606] E connect(5, LEN=2 AF=1 "<anon>", 2): Invalid argument
```

## Instructions

- You will need at 2 terminals open: one for the socat with the display and the other for running the UI container.

### 1. Close any 6000

On a new terminal, verify if there's anything running on port 6000

```
$ lsof -i TCP:6000
$
```

If there is anything, just kill the process

### 2. Close any 6000

Open a socket on that port and keep the terminal open

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
```

### 3. Verify 6000 is open

In a new terminal, verify if it is opened

```
$ lsof -i TCP:6000
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
socat   29298 marcellodesales    5u  IPv4 0xe21e43ca9d99bf1d      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
```

### 4. Build and Run simple UI App

```
$ cat Dockerfile.eyes

FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y x11-apps
RUN rm -rf /tmp/* /usr/share/doc/* /usr/share/info/* /var/tmp/*
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
ENV DISPLAY :0
USER user
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "$0 \"$@\"", "xeyes"]

$ docker build -t eyes -f Dockerfile.eyes .
```

The magic happens using the variables from Docker. Just using the `-e DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0` did the trick, as it it will point to the internal IP address and provide that to the docker image. The port forward will do its magic.

```
$ docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0 eyes
```

[image]

I noticed that at this point XQuartz is opened on it own to the same port

```
$ lsof -i TCP:6000
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
socat   29298 marcellodesales    5u  IPv4 0xe21e43ca9d99bf1d      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
X11.bin 29462 marcellodesales    8u  IPv6 0xe21e43ca7cdb1135      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
```

### 5. Profit and run more apps

```
$ docker run -e DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0 jess/tor-browser
```

[image]

```
$ docker run -e DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0 batmat/docker-eclipse
```

[image]

Comment: This looked promising but the resulted GUI session is unstable (shuts down within 30 seconds without error message. I've read one could use the -t flag somewhere to somehow disable default timeout but there is little documentation on socat and adding the 't ignoreof' in the socat TCP-LISTEN' command certainly doesn't work (in fact socat continues to listen to port 6000 even after the graphical application is shut down). I also get libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Answer (score 2):

I needed to quit Terminal and then relaunch it in order to get it to work.

Comment: The terminal needed to see the new path installed with X. You could add it on the command line but a relaunch of the terminal solves that easily.

Answer (score 2):

For OS X 10.6.3 and later, per [XQuartz 2.7.11 instructions](https://www.xquartz.org/releases/XQuartz-2.7.11.html):

> If this is your first time installing XQuartz, you may wish to **logout and log back in**. This will update your DISPLAY environment variable to point to XQuartz.app rather than X11.app. If you would prefer to keep using X11.app as your default server (you can still launch XQuartz.app manually), you’ll want to disable /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist using [launchctl(1)](https://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).

After installing [XQuartz 2.7.11](https://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) on my macOS High Sierra, logging out of my Mac and logging in again was enough for this to work via my MacOS Terminal. However, you may avoid having to logout and log in by opening the XQuartz Terminal application (**XQuartz > Applications > Terminal**), and running your X application from there. For example:

[image]

and then

```
bash-3.2$ xclock &
```

Comment: > If this is your first time installing XQuartz, you may wish to logout and log back in
Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is possibly limited to MacOS/Monterey.

After running XQuartz and setting the Preferences/Security/"Allow connections from network clients" option, you must restart XQuartz. (It may be the case that after install, you must logoff/logon again, but I found that merely restarting XQuartz was sufficient.) Afterwards, when XQuartz is running again, you should see it listening on port 6000:

```
lsof -i TCP:6000
```

Before this restart step, only `DISPLAY=:0` or the default file-based socket worked for me. After this step, I could then do

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

and `xterm`, `xhost`, etc worked fine.

To use with docker, I used:

```
xhost +localhost
DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0 
docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

Comment: Lifesaver! This is working for me on Ventura. Oddly, XQuartz used to open automatically after connecting via `ssh` then running a command such as `VirtualBox`. In other words, I did not have to manually launch XQuartz and reset the `DISPLAY` variable. Did you experience the same on previous versions of macOS?

Comment: Regarding all of the above, the issue I had was a result of having disabled XQuartz at some point in my Login Items. Reactivating it resolved the `DISPLAY` issue and made it so XQuartz again launches automatically when a window server is requested when connected via `ssh` with `X11` forwarding enabled.

Answer (score -2):

I used this code will help you in macos Big sur
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411619/how-to-make-dia-which-uses-x11-xquartz-work

export DISPLAY=:0           # Fixes the "cannot open display".
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"   # Fixes the annoying Xterm window opening.

exec "$CWD/dia-bin" --integrated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).