# How to embed terminal inside PyQt5 application without QProcess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I have been struggling lately with embedding a terminal inside PyQt GUI app. Tried almost every search on Internet but nothing looks like of any help.

I have a QTabWidget and I simply need one tab to have a terminal.

Is it not at all possible to do so ?

Isn't there something like `QTabWidget.Tab2.show(terminal-app)` and default terminal gets displayed in tab2 and every function like `ls`, `ifconfig`, `cd` etc works fine ?

P.S - I have already tried these but no success. 
[Embedding a terminal in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975678/embedding-a-terminal-in-pyqt5)

(converted code here from PyQt4 to PyQt5 but this does not fulfill my needs) [how to use a terminal embedded in a PyQt GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112349/how-to-use-a-terminal-embedded-in-a-pyqt-gui)

T.I.A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**short answer:** Qt5 does not provide the use of the terminal, so you will have to use QProcess.

**TL;DR**

The EmbTerminal class that is proposed as a solution is a widget so you must add it with `addTab()`, keep in mind that you must have installed the `urxvt` terminal (if you want to check your installation run `urxvt` in the terminal)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class EmbTerminal(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EmbTerminal, self).__init__(parent)
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.terminal = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)
        # Works also with urxvt:
        self.process.start('urxvt',['-embed', str(int(self.winId()))])
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)


class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        lay.addWidget(tab_widget)

        tab_widget.addTab(EmbTerminal(), "EmbTerminal")
        tab_widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QTextEdit(), "QTextEdit")
        tab_widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QMdiArea(), "QMdiArea")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is it ok if I use `self.process.start('xterm',['-into', str(int(self.winId()))])` instead of `self.process.start('urxvt',['-embed', str(int(self.winId()))])` ?

Comment: I ran the code with above change but I simply get a plain EmbTerminal tab. There is nothing in it.

Comment: @v1h5 Do you have xterm installed? to verify it, execute it in the terminal. Both methods work for me.

Comment: Yes I do have xterm installed but looks like something is failing. Please have a look at this screenshot. 
https://ibb.co/jYvZQU

Comment: I am using MacOS High Sierra and Python3.7

Comment: @v1h5 execute `xterm` in your terminal. what is the output. I tested on Linux.

Comment: By simply firing `xterm` is giving me something as below : 
`xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set`

Comment: @v1h5 So that's the problem, try to fix it, I do not have mac so I do not know how to fix it, review forums maybe find a solution.

Comment: but I think xterm needs a display and that's why we pass `-into` with self.winId(). 

Checked whether self.winId() is proper or not. `print(int(self.winId()))` gives me proper output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179790/discussion-between-v1h5-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @v1h5 that command only embeds the terminal in the window, but first the terminal must be opened correctly, check the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826094/xt-error-cant-open-display-if-using-default-display.

Comment: It has started working but terminal opens up in a different window and not inside the tab.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem for a few months now and the urxvt or xterm solution doesn't cut it for me, so I created a repo where I'm working on an easily embeddable terminal for PyQt5.
It works for some commands but for commands like `python` it just has trouble writing into a running process like that.

Feel free to contribute!
https://github.com/Fuchsiaff/PyQtTerminal