# Running the os.system command with the PyQt5 progress bar

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprogressbar

There is a button that runs the `os.system('sudo apt-get update')`command when the button is clicked.

Simultaneously, I'd like to display a progress bar while the command are running.

Should I use Thread?
How can I do this in PyQt5 ?

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Button.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
    def onButtonClick(self):
        os.system('sudo apt-get update')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `apt-get` is not a GUI application and does not show a Qt progress bar.
The Ubuntu `update-amanager` uses python libraries to support aptd and synaptics:
https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/update-manager/main/view/head:/UpdateManager/backend/

You can do the same.

Comment: Or you decide to display the output of `apt-get`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269950/how-to-embed-terminal-inside-pyqt5-application-without-qprocess

Comment: Where is the QProgressBar?..

Comment: I did not add the QProgressbar to know where to use and how to use it. How else can I do this?  Any ideas?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @EnsarKarabudak Your question is confusing, you could detail what you want. Please use `@username`